# Can a hammer concrete drill bit be used with a regular drill for a small project

Tags: mortar, bits

I have to run  a 1/2 inch pvc electrical conduit through a mortar joint

The mfg calls for a 7/8 masonry bit to be used to allow the conduit through.

Have not been able to find such a bit at the big box stores, but did find a 5/8 hammer drill concrete bit.

Will I be able to use that 5/8 hammer bit in a conventional power drill for this small project? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Block and brick, maybe. That's a pretty large hole. I've drilled up to maybe 3/8" through mortar without hammer action, but it's slow.

Concrete, no. Unless your "regular" drill has a hammer mode, you'll spin that bit for an age and not get through concrete. You need impact action to break through the stones.

Comment: I used my cheap Ryobi "regular" drill to drill a 3/4" hole in concrete. Mind you I did a series of pilot holes and took my time. I also turned in from 2 to 1 (speeds) and didn't push too hard. It was hard on my drill, but got the job done. I think this would depend a lot on the aggregate that is present in the concrete. 

Just my two cents.

Comment: Seems like an answer more than a comment, J Crosby.

Comment: It was meant to be a comment on your answer to offer a different perspective. I didn't feel it offered enough to the table to warrant being its own answer.

Comment: It's a process that leads to an outcome. What better answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

If it fits in the drill chuck and it is a mini?? SDS or SDS plus, or spline bit, and is the right size??? (5/8"vs 7/8") or maybe I am missing something here. But I have used the SDS bits in my regular drill in a pinch with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jack....was oping I could enlarge the 5/8 hole slightly bith that 5/8 bit

Comment: Enlarging a hole with the same size bit works only at the entry opening, farther down in the hole depending on its depth it will pretty much stay the same diameter perhaps a little larger but it will be difficult to create the 7/8" hole all the way through like you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You are never going to squeeze 1/2" PVC through a 5/8" hole.  You can find 7/8" plain shank bits at any of the big box stores.

You can usually make small holes in soft masonry without a hammer drill, it takes a bit longer of course.  A 1/4" hole with a masonry bit in a regular drill is no problem except in the very hardest concrete.  A 3/8" hole might try your patience.  A 7/8" hole might take forever, unless you're drilling through some very soft stuff.  I have drilled through old brick that wasn't much harder than drywall.

Answer (score 1):

I would just rent a hammer drill for a day, drill your hole and be done with it.

Maybe drop 20 bucks or so and you buy a one time tool for at least 100 and save the time too.

Comment: I've edited the obvious typos, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the 2nd sentence. Please feel free to [edit] to clarify your meaning. Also, +1 for a very good suggestion (tool rentals are common in the US, but not everywhere). Please also spend a moment to take the [tour] and look through the [help] to see how things work a bit differently here than at discussion boards.

Comment: I am guessing the intent was "rental will probably only cost you $20 on a $120 tool, which is a good deal if you never expect to use it again"?

Comment: This may be so, but it doesn't answer the question.